# mass update from join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables:

```
movies (id, votes)
info (id, movie_id, info_type, value)
```

I want to populate movies.votes with info.value, where movies.id = info.movie_id and info_type = 3 (which is the info type for votes)

I cannot figure out how to do it.. (I'm using SQLite3.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE movies
SET votes = (select value
             from info
             where info.movie_id=movies.id and info_type=3)
WHERE EXISTS 
            (select *
             from info
             where info.movie_id=movies.id and info_type=3)
```

FYI the EXISTS is there so that if there is no `info` data for the movie, those do not get updated to `NULL`.  You can remove it if you want that to happen instead.

Comment: it's VERY slow though.. is that normal? every column has an index.. there are a few hundred thousands so maybe that's normal..

Comment: You're using SQLite for a table with a few hundred thousand rows? Unfortunately with the lack of support for update-from-join, it's going to be bad.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do a multi-table `UPDATE`, which is straightforward in other databases, but according to [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) it looks like you can't do those in sqlite.

In mysql you'd do something like `UPDATE movies JOIN info on (info.movie_id = movies.id) SET votes = info.value WHERE info.info_type = 3`.  I think in sqlite you'll have to separately select all the info values and individually update all the movies records.